# odoo : Changing report name according to view ID

Tags: javascript, odoo, report, qweb

When we create a report (in odoo) and link this report to a model, all views of this model will have the same name of report the print button.

I have a report who are made with T-if conditions to check a report type. 
my question is: how to change report name according to her view?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this issue? Give us some examples so that the users who answer knows what you have tried.

Comment: hi jacques , i have try to use odoo js to user inner text / inner html but that delet actions on buttons ( in cropdown list button) .

Comment: `code
<!-- language: js -->
this.sidebar.$el[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].textContent ="delivery discharge";`

Comment: Which Odoo version using in your working environment?

Comment: i'm using odoo 8

Comment: I thing the righ way is to use button to print report .